# Sia blockchain: Update Allowance Failed ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Tags: blockchain, sia

I am running the [sia UI](https://docs.sia.tech/renting/about-renting) to rent a folder for a website I've created. I am setting up allowance as such:

```
23000 sc allowance
0.00002 TB expected storage
120 months
20 hosts
1 month renew window
0.001 TB expected upload and download
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Update Allowance Failed
ESOCKETTIMEDOUT
```

I am synced, and I have an unlocked sia wallet in my UI with it funded with SC. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

1. Dropped the duration -> 3 months
2. Changed the storage -> 0.001 TB
3. Changed the SC Allocation -> 1000

And contracts were created.